# which template type to use in MSVC/C++: size_t or int

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

MSVC seems to be sensitive to the template type. I have a templated function

```
template<size_t size>
inline double squaredNormOfDiff(const Vec<size>& vec1, const Vec<size>& vec2){
  double sum=0;

  for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++) {
    const double diff = vec1[i] - vec2[i];
    sum += diff * diff;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

When I use it as

```
Vec<3> a, b;
squaredNormOfDiff(a,b);
```

I get an error

```
no instance of function template "raisim::squaredNormOfDiff" matches the argument list
```

But I change the template to

```
template<int size>
```

suddenly it works. I have been using size_t for the template param in Linux. What is the proper way to do it in Windows? or for cross-platform project?

Vec is defined as

```
template <int Size>
using Vec = Mat<Size, 1>;
```

and Mat is defined as

```
template<size_t n, size_t m>
class Mat : public MatExpr<Mat<n, m>> {
  union {
    std::aligned_storage<n*m*sizeof(ScalarType), 32> alignment_only;
    ScalarType v[n * m];
  };        
};
```

Comment: What's the definition of `Vec`?  Please post a [mre] to illustrate.

Comment: I updated my question. could this be due to the template type of Vec<>?

Comment: That's still not a [mre], which is a self-contained minimal example that can be compiled with no modification whatsoever (no missing `#include`s, `main` function, irrelevant code, etc.).  Anyway, I *think* I saw somewhere before that MSVC has a bug related to this ...

Comment: Well, after writing it down, it seems like the problem is the definition of Vec. It worked in Linux/GCC but MSVC is more sensitive...

Comment: If your template takes `size_t` value as parameter then you should pass `size_t` value, not just an `int`. Even though an `int` is implicitly convertable to `size_t`. And it is not a good idea to use an `int` as size type in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to modify Vec and try again:

```
template <size_t Size>   // change to size_t from int to match the definition of Mat
using Vec = Mat<Size, 1>;
```